# Why I need to compile to make groovy code work?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, groovy

I wrote a groovy project with the AST

```
@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties=true)
```

Then I used the new constructor like `new Child(baseP1,baseP2,childP1,childP2)`

When running the code, the eclipse said "Fail to match constructor" for ***all*** constructor in that way.

Then I switch to the IDEA intellij.

Ridiculously ***some*** constructor matched and ***some*** not.

Finally I find a way to make every thing work, that click the compile modules in IDEA.

SO, I want to know

> Why the same groovy code have different behaviors, before and after compiling.

BUG or BY DESIGN or LIMITATION of ide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@TupleConstructor` is an example of [*compile-time* meta-programming](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_compile_time_metaprogramming).

It creates code during the compile phase of your program. Without the compilation step, it just won't have a chance to execute.

Comment: Once I used android annotation which can compile the generated class automatically. Why cannot IDE compile before I run?